# Are walnut tree chips suitable as mulch?

Tags: mulch, walnut

I had to cut a large number of branches from a walnut (its crown started mixing with electric wires). If those branches are chopped (by a machine), can resulting peaces be used as mulch (given juglone content of any walnut)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to grow. Not all plants are sensitive to juglone. According to [this](https://aces.nmsu.edu/ces/yard/2004/100904.html) from a US university, beans, corn, beets, onions, and raspberries are tolerant, for example. Plants that are intolerant include the *Solanaceae* family, (potatoes, tomatoes, etc), blackberries, cabbage, and rhubarb.

If your branches are big enough, walnut wood is valuable for woodworking. Somebody might pay you to take them away, if you can advertise them locally.